# Crear un JTextArea con Scroll

Tags: java

Intento poner Scroll de la siguiente manera:

```
private JPanel crearPanelFijo() {
    listado = new JTextArea(7,20);
    listado.setEditable(false);
    sp = new JScrollPane(listado);
    JPanel jPanelText = new JPanel();
    jPanelText.add(new JLabel("Lista:"));
    jPanelText.add(listado);
    jPanelText.add(sp);
    return jPanelText;
}
```

Pero no me sale el Scroll, simplemente el JTextArea normal.

Me gustaria saber en que fallo.

Gracias

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta

Comment: Si has tecleado el codigo, o si has usado el modo Diseño, un modo grafico donde vas arrastrando los componentes, los Paneles, los scrollbars, los botones...

Comment: Tecleando codigo, creo que ya se porque no me funciona, en vez de usar jPanel deberia usar JFrame

Comment: @FranEET esta bien tu codigo, en tu panel rellenalo con algo y recien aparecera el scroll, rellenalo con letras o imagenes o algo

Comment: ¿Por qué añades `listado` al `JPanel` y al `JScrollPane`?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a añadirle al constructor de `JScrollPane` los siguientes parámetros:

```
JScrollPane scrollBar = new JScrollPane(panel,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

Dependiendo de si quieres que se muestre el scroll vertical/horizontal o los dos, debes añadirle `HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER` o `HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS`

Comment: He puesto esos parametros y ahora me sale un rectangulo diminuto al lado derecho del JTextArea, pero por fuera